# How can I remove the closing square bracket using regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

I have a messy list of strings (`list_strings`), where I am able to remove using `regex` the unwanted characters, but I am struggling to also remove the closing bracket `]` . How can I also remove those ?  I guess I am very close...

```
#the list to clean
list_strings = ['[ABC1: text1]', '[[DC: this is a text]]', '[ABC-O: potatoes]', '[[C-DF: hello]]']

#remove from [ up to : 
for string in list_strings:
  cleaned = re.sub(r'[\[A-Z\d\-]+:\s*', '', string)
  print(cleaned)

# current output

>>>text1]
>>>this is a text]]
>>>potatoes]
>>>hello]
```

**Desired output:**

```
text1
this is a text
potatoes
hello
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
cleaned = re.sub(r'^\[+[A-Z\d-]+:\s*|]+$', '', string)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/BXIZKR) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AjMN0D/1).

Alternatively, to make sure the string starts with `[[word:` and ends with `]`s, you may use

```py
cleaned = re.sub(r'^\[+[A-Z\d-]+:\s*(.*?)\s*]+$', r'\1', string)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AjMN0D/2) and [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/kLrJeJ).

And, in case you simply want to *extract* that text inside, you may use

```py
# First match only
m = re.search(r'\[+[A-Z\d-]+:\s*(.*?)\s*]', string)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))

# All matches
matches = re.findall(r'\[+[A-Z\d-]+:\s*(.*?)\s*]', string)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AjMN0D/3) and [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/1ad3rN).

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `\[+` - one or more `[` chars
- `[A-Z\d-]+` - one or more uppercase ASCII letters, digits or `-` chars
- `:` - a colon
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `]+$` - one or more `]` chars at the end of string.

Also, `(.*?)` is a capturing group with ID 1 that matches any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible. `\1` in the replacement refers to the value stored in this group memory buffer.

Answer (score 4):

Have your code this way. Fixing OP's attempt itself here. Your regex is doing all the thing only point is just add an OR condition where we could mention to substitute 1 or more occurrences of `]` too.

```
import re
list_strings = ['[ABC1: text1]', '[[DC: this is a text]]', '[ABC-O: potatoes]', '[[C-DF: hello]]']
for string in list_strings:
  cleaned = re.sub(r'[\[A-Z\d\-]+:\s+|\]+$', '', string)
  print(cleaned)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use a list comprehension here:

```
list_strings = ['[ABC1: text1]', '[[DC: this is a text]]', '[ABC-O: potatoes]', '[[C-DF: hello]]']
cleaned = [x.split(':')[1].strip().replace(']', '') for x in list_strings]
print(cleaned)  # ['text1', 'this is a text', 'potatoes', 'hello']
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with a different approach to regex using `rstrip()` and `split()` functionality:

```
list_strings = ['[ABC1: text1]', '[[DC: this is a text]]', '[ABC-O: potatoes]', '[[C-DF: hello]]']

cleaned = [s.split(': ')[1].rstrip(']') for s in list_strings]
print(cleaned) # ['text1', 'this is a text', 'potatoes', 'hello']
```